# Webhost and Android Studio

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting

I have an android app I am trying to connect to a webhost. I am getting errors with the following 2 .php files.

```
      connect_db.php

      <?php
      function  
      connecting_db($connect )
    {
        $address= "localhost";
        //$username = "root";
        //$password = "";
        $username = "my_user";
        $password = "my_pass";
        $db="my_datab";
        if( ! $connect = mysqli_connect($address, $username, $password, $db))
        echo "Problem in connecting database";
        return $connect;
      }
    ?>
```

A blank screen comes up.
Then,

```
     get_vehicle.php
     <?php 
     include_once "connect_db.php";
     $connect = null;
     $connect = connecting_db($connect);
     $arr = array();
    if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
    {
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];    
    $query = "select * from  vehicle where user_id =".$user_id;
    $result = mysqli_query($connect , $query);
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        array_push($arr, array("vehicle_id"=>$data['id'],  
"name"=>$data['name'] , "year"=>$data['year'],"fuel_unit"=>$data['fuel_unit']));
    }
    echo json_encode(array("vehicles"=>$arr));
      }
     mysqli_close($connect);
     ?>
```

Here are the errors that come up:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /srv/disk10/2102259/www/vehicletransp.me.pn/connect_db.php on line 18
Problem in connecting database
Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /srv/disk10/2102259/www/vehicletransp.me.pn/get_vehicle.php on line 28

Line 18: if(!$connect = mysqli_connect($address, $username, $password, $db))
Line 28: mysqli_close($connect);
```

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: kindly check your mysql service is working or not and whether you are able to login to mysql shell or any GUI tool like phpmyadmin.

Comment: Hi, I think it is working. I am able to log in to phpmyadmin.